# How to click a button on a Jira ticket using python and the JIRA module

Tags: python, jira, jira-rest-api

We have a process to update a jira ticket which i have automated with the following code and using the JIRA package in python 6.4. Which worked perfectly... however they have added a new step to the process which requires me clicking an 'Approval' button in order for the 'customfield_12410' to appear in a separate pop up window with a load of other fields to update.

```
from jira.client import JIRA
jira_server = "http://jiraserver"
jira_password = f.read()
jira_user = getpass.getuser()
jira_server = {'server': jira_server}
jira = JIRA(options=jira_server, basic_auth=(jira_user, jira_password))
comment = "Test Results. Passes {0} Failed {1}".format(passed,failed)

# Get ticket information
jira_issue = jira.issue(ticketId)

jira_issue.update(fields={'customfield_12410': comment})
```

The error this code now generates is:

```
text: Field 'customfield_12410' cannot be set. It is not on the appropriate 
screen, or unknown.
```

How do i click a button on the Jira ticket. By printing the raw contents of the ticket, i don't see anything resembling the button name.

```
print(jira_issue.raw)
```

Thanks,

John.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved with the following code

```
from jira.client import JIRA
jira_server = "http://jiraserver"
jira_password = f.read()
jira_user = getpass.getuser()
jira_server = {'server': jira_server}
jira = JIRA(options=jira_server, basic_auth=(jira_user, jira_password))
comment = "Test Results. Passes {0} Failed {1}".format(passed,failed)

# Get ticket information
jira_issue = jira.issue(ticketId)

transitions = jira.transitions(jira_issue)
for t in transitions:
    print(t['id'], t['name'])

Output: 
12 Approval
14 Cancel

# Resolve the issue with the comment
jira.transition_issue(jira_issue, '12', fields={'customfield_12410': comment})
```

Comment: Another thing to note.. to get the 'customfield' associated with a named field. (i.e. the 'Comment' field as named in the browser is called 'customfield_12410'). To get the correct association I viewed the html source of the page. (e.g. Right Click on the page > View page source in Chome)

Answer (score 0):

That button is likely a workflow transition. You can change the status using the REST API, examples at https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-questions/JIRA-How-to-change-issue-status-via-rest/qaq-p/528133 and https://jira.readthedocs.io/en/master/examples.html#transitions

Comment: Thanks, this is very useful. I'll update my question with an answer when i have a working solution.